# How can one turn off incoming videos in Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts, video-calling, optimization

I wonder how one can turn off incoming videos in Google Hangouts. I.e., disabling all videos for anybody else in the call when in a videoconference. The motivation is to reduce the network usage.

E.g. in Bluejeans:

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate what did you actually mean by "turning off" incoming videos

Comment: @karthiknair disabling all videos for anybody else in the call when in a videoconference.

The motivation is to reduce the network usage.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't achieve that ; sorry.